# MATLAB: Why is the anoynomous function missing `(t,y)` here?

Tags: matlab

```
function yprime=example1(t , y)
yprime=cos(t)./(2*y-2);

Then type
>> [t,y] =ode45(@example1, [0, 4*pi],3);
>> plot(t , y)
```

On the line `ode45(@example...)`. Why isn't it `ode(@45(t,y)example...)`?. How can `[0, 4*pi]` and `3` be passed into the derivative (i.e. example1) if the input is missing?

Answer (score 2):

The `@` operator can create two (maybe more) different [types of handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html): simple and anonymous.  A simple function handle is one that directly references a function file and has no other levels of in-direction.  An anonymous function is a handle that is itself a (very simple) function and possesses its own workspace for constant storage, closures, and other purposes.  The difference can be seen using the [`functions`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html) function:

```
>> f1 = @example1
f1 = 
    @example1

>> f2 = @(t,x) example1(t,x)
f2 = 
    @(t,x)example1(t,x)

>> functions(f1)
ans = 
    function: 'example1'
        type: 'simple'
        file: 'C:\Development\example1.m'

>> functions(f2)
ans = 
            function: '@(t,x)example1(t,x)'
                type: 'anonymous'
                file: ''
           workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
    within_file_path: '__base_function'
```

Anonymous functions add a bit of overhead due to them being more than just pointers to functions and are therefore only really needed if you're [parameterizing functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html).

Regardless of the creation, `ode45` and its kin will always attempt to pass the `t` and `y` argument pair to the handle you pass it via [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html), and the argument list is only required if you are using anonymous functions versus direct file handle references.

Comment: Worth clarifying is that the `@` operator is an operator for function handles and not for anonymous functions. When writing an anonymous functions similar to `f = @(x,y) x+y;` this actually means, "create a function f(x,y)=x+y; and attach it to the function handle f". Apart from this, great answer! +1.

Comment: @patrik That's a fair point.  I often get lazy and just don't differentiate between the contexts and just think of it as a single, special operator.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how the ode45 function in MATLAB works. 
ode45(@function, [start, end] for t, initial value of y).

So in the example above, function is example1, t0 will be 0, tn (last point) will be 4*pi, and the initial value of y is 3.

The most important part of using ode45 is properly setting up the function. Notice how the function is set for the dy/dt. Because of this, given an initial point, it can generate the rest of the points for y at time t because it can calculate the change in y as t increases.